# Execution of multiple select statements

Tags: java, sql

I want to execute multiple select statements using `GROUP BY`.

I have tried the following one:

```
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT attr_name, count(*)"
                          + " FROM Table_name"
                          + " GROUP BY attr_name;"
                          + "SELECT attr_name, count(*)"
                          + " FROM Table_name"
                          + " GROUP BY attr_name");
```

but it is not coming.

Comment: What do you mean by *it is not coming*?

Comment: You have a semicolon in your query; I would imagine that your query should be one statement as opposed to two.

Comment: Exactly what do you expect? How would the two queries be represented in a single result set? What do you try to achieve? Do you want to repeat the same row 2 times? Why on Earth? Maybe this is what you want: `ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("select attr_name,count(*) from Table_name group by attr_name union select attr_name,count(*) from Table_name group by attr_name");`

Answer (score 2):

The way to join two sets of results is to use `UNION ALL`

```
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(
  "select attr_name,count(*) from Table_name group by attr_name UNION ALL select attr_name,count(*) from Table_name group by attr_name"
);
```

Be careful to make sure that the columns are the same: there must be the same number of columns and they must be of the same type. It would also be worth explicitly naming the columns to make sure: `SELECT attr_name, count(*) AS attr_count FROM...`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing 2 statements in one query. The ResultSet rs is a pointer, that is, it just points to the table row, so we can fetch data based on the attribute name.
In this case, it just doesn't know where to point.

A simple solution, according to me, would be to use a "join", if possible, on the two result sets, so that rs can fetch from appropriate attribute name.
If join is not possible, It would be much better and easier to use multiple ResultSets, and handle your field data, using program logic.